# Unable to capture clicks on Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap 3's dropdown functionality like a select menu.  We will eventually be adding a lot of custom functionality, so we decided to use the dropdown menu instead of the actual select component.  My issue is that I'm unable to capture clicks on the various menu items.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class= "dropdown item-select" id="item-select-1">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Item 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my Javascript:

```
$('#item-select-1 a').on('click', e => {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

But nothing happens when a menu item is clicked; nothing is logged to the console.  Am I overlooking something obvious?  TIA!

EDIT:  I've disabled all other Javascript except for the following.  It might? be significant that the options are not hardcoded into the html; they're dynamically populated in response to the value of another dropdown:

```
$('#category-select').change(e => {
  const opts = state.itemOptions[e.target.value];
  $('.item-select ul').empty().append(opts);
  $('#item-select-1 button').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

And the category selector is like this:

```
<select id="category-select" required="required" name="venue" class="form-control">
  <option>Select Category</option>
  <option>Category 1</option>
  <option>Category 2</option>
  <option>Category 3</option>
  <option>Category 4</option>
</select>
```

EDIT 2:  Alright, so I ran an experiment.  I enabled the dropdown on load and hardcoded some options:

```
<li><a href="#">AAAAAA</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BBBBBB</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CCCCCC</a></li>
```

And it worked.  I guess the issue is the dynamically loaded options.  So I guess I have to re-register the event handlers every time I repopulate the menu options?

Comment: [Just tried it, and its working](https://jsfiddle.net/1fx9hmqc/)

Comment: Probably you have somewhere in your code another click handler, which prevents event bubbeling?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.
Where is your JavaScript script located? Maybe it's not imported to your HTML file properly.

Comment: See my edit.  I have minimal other javascript in the same .js file, and that appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By binding the click handler to an element that is part of the initial load, I am able to capture the click.  `e.target` will give me the exact option that was clicked on:

```
$('#venue-select-1 ul').on('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
});
```